# PL/SQL Help converting an insert statement into a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Hi and thanks for any help,

I have an insert statement that I need to convert into a stored procedure.  I am still a novice to stored procedures and any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Willz06jw

```
Insert Into PRES.PRES1
select distinct pe.pat_id as PATID, pat.pat_mrn_id as PATMRNID, pe.pcp_prov_id as PCPPROVID, pe.department_id as DEPARTMENTID, pe.contact_date as CONTACTDATE, trunc((TO_DATE ('30-09-2013 23:59:59', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - pat.birth_date)/365.25) AS AGE,'' as AGEGROUP, ce.financial_class as FINCLASS
from pat_enc pe
inner join patient pat on pe.pat_id = pat.pat_id
inner join clarity_dep b on b.department_id = pe.department_id
left join clarity_ser cs on pe.visit_prov_id = cs.prov_id
left join zc_def_division zc on cs.def_division_c = zc.def_division_c
inner join hsp_account ha on pe.hsp_account_id = ha.hsp_account_id
inner join clarity_epm ce on ha.primary_payor_id = ce.payor_id
where 
pe.enc_type_c = '101' --2014.09.03 remove virtual visits.. include office visits 101 only  in ('101','1002') 
and (pe.appt_status_c = 2 OR pe.appt_status_c is null)
and (pat.pat_status_c =1 or nvl(pat.pat_status_c,99999) = 99999)  
-- and pe.contact_date between ADD_MONTHS(ENDDATE,-12*1.5) and ENDDATE  -- contact date in last 18 months
and pe.contact_date between TO_DATE('1-OCT-2012','DD-MON-YY') and TO_DATE('30-SEP-2013','DD-MON-YY')  -- contact date in last 18 months
---and trunc((TO_DATE ('30-09-2013 23:59:59', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - pat.birth_date)/365.25) BETWEEN 3 AND 11
and (zc.def_division_c in (26,91,266,329,330,331,332,333,389,402)
or pe.visit_prov_id = pe.pcp_prov_id) 
and ce.financial_class in ('1','3')
and b.DEPARTMENT_ID in (200101,200102,200104,200201,200202,200204,200220,200301,200302,200304,200319,200401,200402,200404,200501,200601,200602,200701,200702,200704,200801,200802,200804,200911,200912,200913,200914,200916,200917,200921,200923,200924,200925,200926,200927,200928,201002,201201,201202,202101,202102,202104,202108,202301,202302,202308,234005,230407,290109)
;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of hard to know which parts of the insert statement are supposed to be parameterized (if any). So here is a simple example to show you the structure of how the stored procedure works which you can modify for you specific requirements.

```
create or replace procedure pres_insert (
    p_contact_date_start      date,
    p_contact_date_end        date
) as
    --declare local variables here if needed.

begin

    insert into <your_table>
    (select distinct *
     from   <from_table> pe
     where  pe.contact_date between p_contact_date_start and p_contact_date_end);

    commit;

end;
```

The main thing to observe is that you can pass parameters to the procedure and use them as required in your insert statement.

Depending on how this is to be used you may not want to include the 'commit' i.e. if this procedure is only one of many that make up a whole 'transaction'.

You may also want to consider and research how you will handle any exceptions inside the procedure.